# What words can be paired with "wreak"?

Tags: phrases, phrasal-verbs

I can think only of havoc. What other things can be wrought in the present tense?

Comment: Mayhem and destruction come to mind.

Comment: Wreak vengeance

Comment: I've seen some posts here that wreaked of lousy spelling.

Comment: As an aside, as per the online Oxford Dictionary: The phrase wrought havoc, as in they wrought havoc on the countryside, is an acceptable variant of wreaked havoc. Here, wrought is an archaic past tense of work. It is not, as is sometimes assumed, a past tense of wreak.

Comment: @StevenLittman The confusion may be due to the similarity between *wrought* (archaic past participle of *work*) and *wroke* (strong past tense of *wreak*). *Wreak* once followed the same paradigm as modern *speak*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A search for the collocate *wreak [noun]* on the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) (1990–2012) turns up the following results and relative frequencies (#5 and #6 being obvious typos):

1. ```
     HAVOC  425
   ```
2. ```
     VENGEANCE  15
   ```
3. ```
     DESTRUCTION    7
   ```
4. ```
     REVENGE    5
   ```
5. ```
     HAVOE  1
   ```
6. ```
     HAVOC.WHETHER 1
   ```
7. ```
     BRUTALITIES 1
   ```
8. ```
     CATASTROPHE 1
   ```
9. ```
     TURMOIL    1
   ```
10. ```
     HORROR 1
    ```
11. ```
     CHAOS  1
    ```
12. ```
     HARM   1
    ```
13. ```
     TERROR 1
    ```
14. ```
     DESERT 1
    ```
15. ```
     DAMAGE 1
    ```
16. ```
     BUDGET 1
    ```
17. ```
     VIOLENCE   1
    ```

In the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/), the results are similar:

1. ```
     HAVOC  37
   ```
2. ```
     VENGEANCE  7
   ```
3. ```
     REVENGE    4
   ```
4. ```
     MAYHEM 2
   ```
5. ```
     PUNISHMENT 1
   ```
6. ```
     MAGIC  1
   ```
7. ```
     INHUMANITY 1
   ```
8. ```
     DESTRUCTION    1
   ```

The [Corpus of Historical American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) (1810–2009) also favors *havoc* and *vengeance* by a wide margin, with *vengeance* appearing earliest, but *havoc* becoming dramatically popular in the postwar years:

1. ```
     HAVOC  72
   ```
2. ```
     VENGEANCE  45
   ```
3. ```
     REVENGE    7
   ```
4. ```
     DESTRUCTION    4
   ```
5. ```
     EVIL   2
   ```
6. ```
     VIOLENCE   2
   ```
7. ```
     TURMOIL    1
   ```
8. ```
     SUMMARY    1
   ```
9. ```
     REVENGES   1
   ```
10. ```
     HORROR 1
    ```
11. ```
     DEVASTATION    1
    ```
12. ```
     DESERT 1
    ```
13. ```
     CHAOS  1
    ```
14. ```
     BRUTALITIES    1
    ```
15. ```
     AFTER-VENGEANCE    1
    ```

Searching on *wreaking* and other forms seems to indicate that just about anything negative can be *wreaked* —  *carnage*, *injustice*, *disruption*, *plague*, etc. But I don't have time to research if there's any particular reason why *havoc*, *vengeance* / *revenge*, and *mayhem* rose to the top.

As to *budget* and the like, the oddities mostly arise from their use as attributives; thus they are classified as a noun, but the direct object of *wreak* lies beyond— *wreak budget disaster*, *wreak summary vengeance*, etc. It can also arise where a following noun is not the direct object, for example where the infinitive *to wreak* is used: *His parents were away for the long weekend, and with three days of havoc to wreak, teenagers soon flooded the tiny bungalow.*